# UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted with feature names warnings.warn(

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrbpx.png) Help please?

Already tried adding .values to the X's, still resulted in an error. Any suggestions?

```
X = df[['Personal income','Personal saving']]
y = df['Gross domestic product'] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

sample = [10000, 1000]
sample_pred = regr.predict([sample])
```

Comment: please provide sample data. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what's the warning ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this issue https://github.com/tylerjrichards/Getting-Started-with-Streamlit-for-Data-Science/issues/5 , converting X_train dataframe to np array (X_train.values) before fitting removes the warning.

it did for my testing : you can either try :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.values, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.to_numpy(), y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

In addition, this warning doesn't affect the calculation precision, you can ignore it and continue working until the update of the versions of libraries.